# Joomla 1.5 on WampServer 2.2E loads slowly, shows blank page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, joomla, wampserver

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad running Win7 Pro 64 bit, on which I've installed Wampserver 2.2E 64 bit.  I've installed a copy of a Joomla 1.5 site which I want to upgrade; my plan is to test the upgrade process on the laptop.  I can load the *Localhost* page and *phpMyAdmin* with no trouble, but when I try to load the Joomla site, it takes over 5 minutes to load (I timed it) and then displays a blank page.

Because I run IIS7.5 on port 80 to support another test site, I've configured Wampserver apache to run on port 8080, and the apache logs show that it is listening on that port.  The error log doesn't actually show any errors, here's a typical Apache startup:

```
[Mon Nov 25 17:41:20 2013] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[Mon Nov 25 17:41:20 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2680
[Mon Nov 25 17:41:20 2013] [notice] Child 2680: Child process is running
[Mon Nov 25 17:41:20 2013] [notice] Child 2680: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Nov 25 17:41:20 2013] [notice] Child 2680: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Nov 25 17:41:20 2013] [notice] Child 2680: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.
```

The PHP error log is blank and always has been.  The mySQL log also looks normal (latest startup):

```
131125 17:41:20 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131125 17:41:20 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131125 17:41:20 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
131125 17:41:20 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
131125 17:41:20 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131125 17:41:20 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131125 17:41:20 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131125 17:41:20  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131125 17:41:21 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595685
131125 17:41:21 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
131125 17:41:21 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
131125 17:41:21 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
131125 17:41:21 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
131125 17:41:21 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
131125 17:41:21 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.24-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I've been researching this problem for several days and have tried a number of changes, none of which has had any effect.  Here's my list of failed tries:

1. Made following changes to httpd.conf and php.ini:
   EnableMMAP on
   EnableSendfile on
   Enable and set realpath_cache_size= 4m to your php.ini file
   (It turns out I had only set the size; enabling means uncommenting the previous line in php.ini.  I think.  Uncommenting the line doesn't seem to have any effect.)
2. Uncommented this line in \etc\hosts:    ::1  localhost  (have since recommented as it had no effect.)
3. Adding the line  127.0.0.1  127.0.0.1 to \etc\hosts.  Have since removed; had no effect.
4. Replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 in httpd.conf
5. Verified that the system nameservers are not hardcoded and are being pulled from the DHCP server.  For the record our router's nameservers are 
   68.94.156.1 dnsr1.sbcglobal.net and 68.94.157.1 dnsr2.sbcglobal.net
6. Configured mysql.default_host and mysqli.default_host (in php.ini) to localhost, then to 127.0.0.1; neither had any effect.

Can anyone suggest something that I haven't tried?  This smells like a problem with php or mysql but neither one is logging any problems.

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem with the server and not the joomla installation

Comment: Mainly because the joomla installation is a copy of a production site which is running well, and was copied over using instructions I developed (from Joomla doc and personal experience), which have worked for copies of this site before.  It COULD be a joomla problem and I'd like to open a question in the joomla forums, but you have to use their fpa-en.php utility or they won't look at your query; and I can't get the utility to run on the test site. It loads but never puts up a form.

Comment: If you use a fresh copy of joomla and import the database from the installation (rather than the files as well), does it work?  can you enable error reporting in the config file? `$error_reporting = 'development';` and does it throw anything? Also, can you limit the max execution of scripts to something more reasonable like say 30 seconds for instance.

Comment: I've changed the $error_reporting value to 'development' and will check on it.  I'm not sure I can still get a fresh copy of joomla 1.5 but i'll see if i can find it.  Here's the max execution parm from php.ini:  max_execution_time = 30  If that isn't 30 seconds how do i set it?

Comment: If it's a fresh copy of Joomla 1.5 and it's running slow then don't worry. Localhosts can run a CMS based site slowly depending on a few things such as PC performance, CPU usage etc. When you move it to an online host, thing will go back to normal speeds, providing the host is decent

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem in your case as I am not actually sure what you are doing, but Joomla installs normally take quite a chunk of processing time.

You normally need to increase the execution time to get them to complete properly.

Try setting `max_execution_time = 300` in the `php.ini` file and restarting `Apache`

Of course if that works, remember to set `max_execution_time` back to something sensible, no more that 60.

Comment: This isn't a Joomla install. I'm trying to move a copy of an existing Joomla site to the Wampserver on my laptop.  I've done it before.  I take a sql dump of the database and download all the files; I put the files in the directory and import the tables into a database with the correct name and username on the SQL server, and it usually comes right up.  And by "right up" I do mean 30-50 seconds; my problem is that it's taking 5 _minutes_ and then showing blank.  I'm downloading a fresh copy of the site in case the other copy got corrupted.

Comment: And yes, I am updating the configuration.php to show the local URLs.

Comment: @hedera Like I said, I am not sure if this is your problem. Jeessss give a guy a break. Only trying to help. Did you check the apache error log and/or the php error log??

Comment: sorry - didn't mean to come on hard, this is driving me nuts.  Those logs are part of what drives me nuts.  The Apache error log shows zero errors, just normal startup and listen on the correct port.  The PHP error log is blank and always has been.